# Lots of users still using 1.5?

Tags: android

I'm looking at market stats here for sdk distribution:

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

saying that 31% of marketplace users are still running 1.5. Is it true that an OS update went out for G1 and myTouch users? I'm wondering why so many people are still running 1.5 if so? Just curious because I'd like to use th setView() method introduced in 1.6 for TabSpec, but not if so many people are still using 1.5, I might have to roll my own control,

Thanks

Comment: 1.5 is popular because the HTC devices with the proprietary UI can only run 1.5.  G1 and the myTouch 3G have had 1.6 forever.

Comment: Hi I don't understand - which HTC devices have a 'proprietary UI'? I thought the HTC devices are the G1 and myTouch - ?

Comment: HTC has other devices that do not run the stock Android UI: the HTC Hero for instance. Motorola also released phones running on 1.5, for instance their new Backflip.

Comment: I have a HTC Magic running 1.6.  The OS was last updated back in October.  2.0 and 2.1 are both out but no sign of an update, and I can't see me getting one, either.

Answer (score 1):

Many devices are being announced with 1.5 but will be upgraded before or soon after launch, as I see it many rooted phones that came with 1.5 or lower are almost all at 1.6. Some $100 devices announced will never go higher than 1.6 because of performance issues unless Google actually optimizes newer versions of Android.

The htc Magic(Mytouch) and htc Dream(G1) here in canada only officially have a 1.5 update and no 1.6. But in the USA they now have 1.6. I have a Dream and I rooted it and have firmware 1.6 but I have run 2.0, 2.01, 2.1 on it but performance is not too great on it. With 1.6 I can play apparently slow games on it at a decent speed.

Google also stated that they will update most android devices to have 2.1. So I would think that All Htc and Motorola phones will end up with 2.1. Just give me a moment to find the source of this.

[All US Android phones to have 2.1](http://androidandme.com/2010/02/news/all-u-s-android-phones-to-receive-android-2-1-but-some-will-require-a-wipe/)

Devices that have a custom ui are: (These are the devices that I know of but there are more)
Sence UI

```
HTC Magic in canada
HTC Hero
```

MotoBlur

```
Backflip
Click
Click xt
```

There are custom roms that enable sence ui and motoblur for motorola phones and htc phones. For example I have run sense ui and motoblur on my Dream.

Answer (score 0):

Reports suggest that most devices will be upgraded to 2.0 in the coming months and those that aren't will be running 1.6.

So you have to weigh up the advantage of using the setView() method over the potential loss in device compatibility.

Comment: A lot of devices are going to remain on 1.5 for a long time, as the majority of devices out there don't support OTA updates.

Answer (score 0):

strangly enough LG is just releasing a new phone based on 1.5

http://www.reghardware.co.uk/2010/03/17/review_phone_lg_gw620/

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the users running 1.5 on my HTC Hero, this is not because I don't want to update but because they haven't released it yet, fortunately 2.1 is being released in April for Orange customers in the UK.

Furthermore the reason some devices take some time to upgrade are mostly due to HTC improving and upgrading the SenseUI, it's what I was told when I asked them anyway.

HTC Hero being upgraded to 2.1 on 26th April in Taiwan, a day or two after rest of the world

Source: http://www.androidcentral.com/htc-hero-gets-21-upgrade-april-26th-%E2%80%93-taiwan